# How do you get rid of a program that you don't have access to delete? (Virus - SearchProtect)

Tags: windows-7, windows, virus

I've been trying to get rid of this highly malicious program called SearchProtect. Every few seconds I see my anti-malware program popup, blocking this program. I deleted it from the uninstall programs list, but when I later went into the program files, its still there! I try to delete it right there, but I won't delete because I dont have access. I locate it's process and try to end it but it denies my access to end it. The malicious process is C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dllhost.exe   - and the domain ff5ee.com is also involved. How do I remove this virus, or these viruses. I know the program "SearchProtect" has something to do with it.

Comment: [Remove Win32/Conduit.SearchProtect.H (Removal Guide)](http://malwaretips.com/blogs/win32-conduit-searchprotect-h-removal/)

Comment: Nuke it from orbit, its the only way to be sure. I *guess* you might be able to delete it from a livecd, but doing a full system rebuild is the way to go here.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the tool [Rkill](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/download/rkill/). It will kill the malicious program's background process. Next, run [AdwCleaner](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/download/adwcleaner/). It will delete SearchProtect's files along with any other adware you have installed. If neither of these work, comment on this answer and I can give you a few more tips.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can right click the folder, 
1.select properties
2. then go to security, 
3.find "For special permissions or advanced settings, click Advanced.", click Advanced
4.here, you can check the owner, and change it your account, you might have one popup for confirmation
5.After that, you should have access to delete the folder

Additional, i would recommend you to choose one better antivirus software which can detect the potential unwanted programs. I am using malwarebytes (it's not an antivirus software actually, but it help you with better protection) on my own pc

Hope this can help you

Answer (score 0):

Try removing its registry items, though it can be risky to do so. Make a backup first. Then search for items of searchprotect, ff5ee. com or other programs that you might think to be suspicious. The registry files are essential to reinstatement of those pesky stuff. Here's a [similar post](http://blog.doohelp.com/how-to-get-rid-ofremove-web-protect-ads-virus-removal/) to check.